# How pass a queue of data from kernel to user space?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, shared-memory

I'm currently writing a module for Linux, and I want to pass a queue of data from kernel to user space (my program in userland being responsible for read this data - and then responsible for writing those to a file), and my approach is to get a memory location in user space and push data from kernel to it.

How can I implement it?

Do you have a better approach? I'm Beginner, and any guides can be nice.

Before that, I try to push this data to user space with IOCTL and PROCFS but that approach is not a good idea and I lost some data.

Comment: What sort of module is this ? some device-driver ? What sort of "kernel data" do you want to pass to userland ? (some device's buffer ?) Asking just in case since since depending on your answer there is just a simple and secure way to achieve your goal or there is a not-that-simple and potentially dangerous way to proceed. IOW : Please be more verbose about your project.

Comment: I'm trying to write a Linux module that monitors all system calls and sends a system call log (data struct) to my program in user space. The information such as who PID calls system call, what arguments passed, etc.
example: a tool like strace in Linux.
before that, I tried to pass this data from kernel space to userland with IOCTL, PROCFS, etc. I think those approaches are not a good idea because I have a lot of data that must be quickly passed to userland.
I'm decision use copy a data to a memory address of userland. excuse me for my bad English. :\

Comment: Since you self claim being a beginner and what you want to achieve actually needs a fair level of understanding of the linux kernel, I would strongly invite you to first get familiar with **strace**, and start from its code (https://github.com/strace/strace) to implement the functionalities you realize would be missing.

Comment: thanks, I wrote all function that is needed, and in the last step, I want to pass created data to userland. but I don't know which approach is best/worked.

Comment: Then if the standard procfs way cannot fit your needs, Your userland task will have to go and fetch the data on its own using /dev/mem. Looking into busybox' devmem code would not be a bad idea for a start and HAVE A GOOD LUCK being the best wish I can sincerely provide.